# how do I customise my text to speech voice for the IBM Watson unity SDK?

Tags: unity-game-engine, ibm-watson, watson-text-to-speech

I've got IBM's Watson text to speech for the unity SDK working beautifully but only the female american voice. I now need them to be either British or at least one male voice. I'm scottish so voice recognition is always a pain.

can someone tell me if I need to do it differently to the guide for other platforms,

Answer (score 2):

`Voice` is a property of the TextToSpeech class. Once you create an instance of TextToSpeech (in this case called textToSpeech) you can

```
textToSpeech.Voice = VoiceType.en_GB_Kate;
```